# 400 Bad Request when same method called from different JSP gets 200 response

Tags: jsp, jquery, spring-mvc, http-headers

Kind of puzzled by response. I am calling the same method through ajax call from different JSP page and I get a different `HTTP response`. One gives 200 whereas the other give 400. Why so?

The only difference between to `JSP` pages are the `level/depth`

Example

```
  main.jsp is at level localhost/appname/main.htm
  other.jsp is at level localhost/appname/myworld/other.htm
```

URL to post Ajax call is same for both

```
    function getResponse(value) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/posthere/callme.htm',
            data: {
                valueId: value,
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data == true) {
                    console.log("Success: ");
                } else {
                    console.log("Failed: ");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/posthere")
@SessionAttributes({"userSession"})
public class MyController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/callme", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public @ResponseBody
   boolean getcalled(@RequestParam("valueId") String valueId,
                               @ModelAttribute("userSession") UserSession userSession,
                               HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
      if(userSession != null) {
          //do your magic. Note: This logic is not getting invoked. I have a breakpoint here.
          return true;
      }
      return false; 
   }
}
```

Comment: please post full code that performs request, as well as your controller method that handles those request.

Comment: Added most of the code

Answer (score 2):

check the content Type. I faced this issue when the content type was X and i was sending something which is not equivalent to X.

Comment: Yes but I am sending exactly the same call in both place. Code is cut copy paste. Whats the difference. I know the context type for the bad response is Content-Type:text/html. But the request for both of them are exact.

Answer (score 2):

Check what are you passing as `valueId` in both cases.
If it can't be interpreted as a `String` (which is unlikely) or is not present, you'll get `400 Bad request`.

Your case is probably the second one: when `idValue` is `undefined`, it **will not be sent at all**, so Controller receives incomplete data - hence the `400 Bad request`.

Comment: Hmm. This will turn out to be something very minor. Will look at it with fresh eyes again